# IE tabs are not running in 64 bit mode even after enabling Enhanced protected mode

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8, internet-explorer-11

I would like to run my desktop IE tabs in 64 bit mode.
As described by Microsoft I have enabled IE enhanced protected mode using IE Tools->Advanced options. I have also enabled "Enabled 64 bit processes for enhanced protected mode".
Nevertheless I am unable to see IE tabs running in 64 bit mode.

Note: I am using IE11 in Windows 8.1 64 bit machine.

Comment: Did you restart all instances? Are you visiting a site in a Zone where Protected Mode is enabled (e.g. the Internet Zone)?

Comment: Are you using the Modern version or the Desktop version?

Comment: Just tried enabled "enhanced protected mode" and restarted all instances (verified on Taskmanager). Tabs keeps open as `iexplore.exe*32`

Comment: I am using Desktop version of IE. I have not open any website. I just registered my BHO, and when I open IE it ask me for enabling it , after enabling if I go to Manage addons , I could able to see my BHO status as enabled , architecture as 32bit & 64 bit.I just launch IE which comes with one tab by default. If we look at the task manager there will be two IE process. One for each tab and one for main IE. That main IE process is 64 bit but tab is running as 32 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

Actually we have to enable the UserAccountControl setting.
I did it by making EnableLUA 1 in the below mention key

HKLM->Software->Microsoft->Windows->CurrentVersion->policies->System

Comment: Windows 8.1 enterprise. Already had UAC on and can't get tabs to run 64bit.

Comment: windows 7 - same as above.

Comment: Same as for Windows 10 v.1511

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to add a registry key in:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth with value 0.

Works for Windows7 and IE11 (see here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2716529)

You could use a reg file instead of manually setting the registry key. Just save the below text in a file named as `key.reg` and double-click to execute it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00    
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"TabProcGrowth"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: This seems to be the most useful solution, especially if you are only using 64 bit add-ons anyway. +1

Comment: Worked for me as well. Note that it also means IE11 won't create any child processes for tabs - you get a single 64-bit process for all the tabs.

Answer (score 2):

If UAC is off, then Enhanced Protected Mode doesn't do anything.

So you should try turning on UAC:

```
Open User Account Control Settings by clicking the Start button, and 
then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type uac, and then click
Change User Account Control settings.

To turn on UAC, move the slider up from the bottom position, to choose when you want to be notified, and then click OK. If you're prompted for an administrator password or
confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
```

Answer (score 2):

Another reason it is that the `Isolation64Bit` reg value might be set.

Check in IE `Tools -> Options -> Advanced` and untick `Enable 64-bit Processes for Enhanced Protected Mode` if it's ticked.

Alternatively check the following reg keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Isolation64Bit
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Isolation64Bit
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Isolation64Bit
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Isolation64Bit
```

and if any of them exist (and are set to 1) then set it to 0 or delete it.

Comment: Shouldn't Enable 64-bit Processes for Enhanced Protected Mode be ticked though? It's supposed to enable 64-bit processes.

Comment: I see your point, unfortunately I can't remember why this worked from 4 years ago... In the weird and wonderful world of IE configuration I wouldn't be surprised if some combinations of registry values did the wrong thing.  The default state of a windows installation is, I believe, that `Isolation64Bit` is missing from the registry so it's worth trying that.